# Java Streams to find elements in a list of mapLists

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

Can you help me converting the below logic to make use of streams. This works fine but i want to use streams instead of this

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list1=new ArrayList<>();
List<Map<String, Object>> list2= new ArrayList<>();
for ( Map<String, Object> datElement: list()) {
   for (Entry<String, Object> val : datElement.entrySet()) {
      if (val.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("rateID") ) {
         //int kel = (int) val.getValue();
         if ( val.getValue().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
            list1.add(datElement);
         } if (val.getValue().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            list2.add(datElement);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list1= list().stream()
      .map(l -> 
            l.entrySet().stream()
                  .filter( obj -> obj.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("rateID"))
                  .map( obj -> obj.getValue().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
            
      ).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Maps are optimized for key lookup. Why would you iterate over the entry set to find a specific key?

Comment: Possibly the `ignoringCase` option isn't available to the OP.  I'll admit that this still doesn't seem like a good idea though.

Comment: You’d handle that by lower casing the keys when you add them to the map, and when you do a lookup.

Comment: @markspace well, having e.g. `equalsIgnoreCase("0")` in the OP’s code suggests that the OP didn’t think about the semantics of the string comparison at all. Likewise, the spelling of `"rateID"` (and the identifier itself) suggests that actually, a case sensitive match is intended and therefore, just calling `get("rateID")` would do the job. I don’t know why people so often use `equalsIgnoreCase` when they actually mean `equals`, but it happens quite often. Maybe, there’s an editor automatically inserting the longest possible alternative on code completion?

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> list1 = list.stream()
            .filter(datElement -> datElement.containsKey("rateID"))
            .filter(datElement -> datElement.get("rateID").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<Map<String, Object>> list2 = list.stream()
            .filter(datElement -> datElement.containsKey("rateID"))
            .filter(datElement -> datElement.get("rateID").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks for your input but my key and values are in a list which is inside a list so can you help me something like below:
list.stream().filter( subList ->{
   subList .stream().filter( val -> val.containsKey(")
}

Comment: Im thinking about something like this but getting compilation errors as bad return type lamda expression
`
mainList().stream()
 .filter(mListEle -> mListEle.entrySet().stream()
       .filter( sList -> 
sList.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("rateID"))
          .filter(sList -> sList.getValue().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("0")))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());`